# Embedding Powerpoint presentation in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I need to preview uploaded powerpoint file like slideshare does.

I tried using iframe but it is not working. It downloads the file directly. I'm using:

```
<iframe src="file_url" height="200px" width="200px"></iframe>
```

I have also tried using some plugins like Embed Any Document, Google Doc Embedder etc but it is also not working. It is displaying "no preview available."

Thanks in advance.
Any help is appreciated.